Bathroom fan odor counteractant replacement
What I'm working on: https://imgur.com/a/uxRZesI
I am replacing this Broan-nutone bathroom "odor counteractant" fan that doesn't vent out of the bathroom. It has a smelly puck that the fan blows air over. It's stamped Oct 1988 and the smelly puck still smells!
The toilet below this fan is separated from the rest of the bathroom with a wall and door. The rest of the bathroom has a large window and an HVAC register. I think that may have been enough for code (in Socal)?
I would like to replace this thing with a ventilating fan, but maybe it's not necessary given the layout. It is really only used for a light.
I could use some advice from any pros that might know about this stuff. Thanks.

The idea of an "odor reducing" recirculating fan seems like a bad joke (on the consumer). The "puck" might have been activated charcoal, but it wouldn't have been very effective after a few weeks. If you don't need a noisy fan, replace with a light. Otherwise, use a fan with a vent hose, reducing humidity, as well as stench.
